# Grep command to extract a kubernetes pod name for logs

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I need to view logs a pod of specific name:
Basically, I want to see logs for the pod having name `infra` in it.

I'm using below command:

```
kubectl logs $(kubectl get pods | awk '{print $1}' | grep -e "infra")
```

But, it's not working.

Comment: What happens when using this command? What's the output of `kubectl get pods` and `kubectl get pods | awk '{print $1}'`?

Comment: Would be easier to use a label selector `kubectl logs -l app=my-app --all-containers --ignore-errors` or use a tool like [stern](https://github.com/stern/stern)

Answer (score 1):

The [`stern`](https://github.com/stern/stern) command make this very simple:

```
stern infra
```

That will stream the logs from any pods that have `infra` in the name.

---

But even without `stern`, you can do something like:

```
kubectl logs $(kubectl get pods -o name | grep infra)
```

That will work as long as your `grep` command returns a single line. If the `grep` command results in multiple matches, you'll need to use a more specific pattern.

If you want to see logs from multiple pods with a single command, you can request logs by label using `kubectl logs -l <label>`. E.g., if I have several pods with the label `app=my-app`, I can run:

```
kubectl logs -l app=my-app
```